# Set new image size in wordpress with only one dimension

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I wonder - how can i add a new image size to wordpress but only with one certain length to work both for horizontal and vertical images?

What i have is following code:

```
function custom_image_sizes() {
  add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
    add_image_size( 'isotopesize', 600, 600, true ); //(cropped)
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'custom_image_sizes');

function add_custom_sizes( $imageSizes ) {
  $my_sizes = array(
        'isotopesize' => 'Isotope'
    );
    return array_merge( $imageSizes, $my_sizes );
}
add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', 'add_custom_sizes' );
```

But it adds a square = 600x600px. What I wanted to achieve is to set only one dimension: 600px and let wordpress decide how long will be second dimension. What I would like to achieve is to always keep same row height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the solution [found here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73058/how-to-crop-thumbnail-height-to-auto-with-set-width) which is essentially to set the width to a giant number that will never be reached.

```
add_image_size( 'isotopesize', 9999, 600, false );
```